# Datatable not loading saying awaiting activation json

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I am trying to use a datatable and was wondering what i am doing wrong its just stuck on loading and showing waiting to start. This is on my activity controller and the LoadGridData function is called from the scripts below in my index.cshtml.

```
public ActionResult LoadGridData()
{                     
        // Getting all Customer data    
        var data = GetAllActivityHeader();           

        return Json(new {  data = data });
 }
```

Here is my GetallActivityHeader function

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<ActivityHeader>>> GetAllActivityHeader()
{
        return await _activityRepo.GetAllActivityHeader();
 }
```

This is my repositry method which is called above.

```
public async Task<List<ActivityHeader>> GetAllActivityHeader()
{           
     using (IDbConnection conn = Connection)
     {
           if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
              conn.Open();

            var result = await conn.QueryAsync<ActivityHeader>("GetActivityHeader");
            return result.ToList();
      }         
}
```

In My Layout I have the following scripts

```
@section Scripts{
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
</script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Activity/LoadGridData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Description", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Phone", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "EmployeeName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "SOP", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Status", "autoWidth": true }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html

```
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
     <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>EmployeeName</th>
                <th>SOP</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>                    
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

But when i debug the code i am getting the following issue. Also for some reason my edit and delete buttons are not showing I persume i need to code those before they show. Is there any better components for working with datatables and asp.net core?.

[image]

And also here is what my view is showing

[image]

**Edit 1**
Ok so i made the method async and that worked and there data their but its still saying no data in the datatable

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> LoadGridData()
    { 

       // Getting all Customer data    
        var data = await GetAllActivityHeader();           

        return Json(new {  data = data });
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Finally this is my class obv I dont want to display all in the datatable so I just used the column headers i wanted or is that not how datatables work?.

Comment: Problem is not related to datatable. Problem in your repository method `GetAllActivityHeader` which is not returning the data list correctly.

Comment: How is it not please provide an example its a list not a single record